# SQL What Percentage of payments this year were card vs bank

Tags: sql, formula, payment, percentage

I am looking to find the percentage of credit card payments vs bank payments, within a specific date range.

I am expecting to find the percentage of the processed credit card payments vs bank payments. I have filtered my list to show the processed credit card payments and bank payments made within the specified date range, but I need to figure out the subquery to find the amount of credit card payments vs bank payments within that filtered table.

What I have is:

```
SELECT payment_method, date(created_at), status
FROM production.payments
WHERE created_at >= ‘2023-01-01’
   and payment_method != ‘cash’
   and status != ‘failed’
```

This has given me the data I need to pull from (all credit card payments and bank payments made this year), but now I need to gather the count of all the credit card payments and the count of all the bank payments (separately)

| Payment_method | Created_at |
| --- | --- |
| Card | 2023-01-01 |
| Card | 2023-01-01 |
| Card | 2023-01-01 |
| Bank | 2023-01-01 |
| Bank | 2023-01-01 |
| Card | 2023-01-02 |
| Bank | 2023-01-03 |
| Card | 2023-01-03 |
| Card | 2023-01-03 |
| Bank | 2023-01-04 |
| Card | 2023-01-04 |
| Card | 2023-01-05 |

Desired output - the number of times each has been used this year (I can then figure out the percentage)

| Payment_method | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Card | 5,061 |
| Bank | 8,632 |

OR

Desired output - percentage of credit card payments vs bank payments

| Payment_method | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| Card | 37% |
| Bank | 63% |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrap your query in cte.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT payment_method, date(created_at), status
    FROM production.payments
    WHERE created_at >= ‘2023-01-01’
       and payment_method != ‘cash’
       and status != ‘failed’
)
SELECT DISTINCT payment_method
, 100.00 * COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY payment_method) / COUNT(*) OVER() AS [Percentage]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I am getting Card 131014.5 Bank 71166.0 

I used your exact formula, am I missing something that I must input??

Comment: The `GROUP BY` may have messed up the calculation.  I modified the query.

Comment: I was able to wrap the second portion of Isolated's answer in your CTE and got the percentages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate each group and then divide by total....

```
create table payments (
  payment_method varchar(10), 
  created_at date
  );
  
insert into payments values 
('card', '2023-01-01'),
('card', '2023-01-01'),
('card', '2023-01-01'),
('card', '2023-01-01'),
('card', '2023-01-01'),
('card', '2023-01-01'),
('card', '2023-01-01'),
('bank', '2023-01-01'),
('bank', '2023-01-01');
```

---

```
select payment_method, 
 round(count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () * 100 ,2) as pct_of_total
from payments
--where your criteria
group by payment_method;
```

| payment_method | pct_of_total |
| --- | --- |
| card | 77.78 |
| bank | 22.22 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eYE9ncfm52a4SoBNV53Jry/3)

Comment: Thank you! Looks like the formula wrapped in CTE is what I am looking for - just unsure why I am not getting a percentage.

Comment: I was able to wrap the second portion in Eric's CTE and got the percentages. Thanks!